# Forest plot: Error during wrapup: Final variance-covariance matrix not positive definite

Tags: r, error-code, metafor

I am trying to create a forest plot using  `metafor` package and wrote the following code

```
metrics = metadata1 %>%
  pull(measurement_n) %>%
  unique()


output = map(metrics, 
             function(i)  metadata1 %>%
               filter(measurement_n==i) %>%
               mutate(experiment = paste(feedstock, type_of_climate, study_area, paper_type) %>%
                        as.factor() %>%
                        as.numeric(),
                      lbl = paste0(author_year)) %>%
               rma.mv(lnrr, v, random = ~ 1 | publication_title/experiment, data=.))
```

But I am constantly getting the following errors

```
Error during wrapup: Final variance-covariance matrix not positive definite.
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
```

Does anyone know how to solve this error? Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: As there is a limited character, I could only post the first row of a data frame. metadata_dput <- dput(metadata1[1:1, c(3, 4, 7, 9, 10, 16, 23, 54, 67)]) 
structure(list(publication_year = 2020, publication_title = "Biochar alters nitrogen and phosphorus dynamics in a western rangeland ecosystem", 
    study_area = NA_character_, continent = "North America", 
    type_of_climate = "Temperate continental", measurement_n = "Soil nutrient content", 
    feedstock = "Wood", lnrr = 0.0399166074054424, v = 0.00527269062850407), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))